# when joining two tables using union how to use order by clause for two tables seperatly in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

i am creating two tables with same type of attributes i have to join these tables using union in such a way that the resultant union set should have 1st table in ascending order and 2nd table in descending order

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from ((select t1.*, 1 as which
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.*, 2 as which
       from t2
      )
     ) t
order by which,
         (case when which = 1 then col end) asc,
         (case when which = 2 then col end) desc;
```

Comment: You only need one pair of parentheses around the union, there is no need to put each union query between parentheses as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I know.  I like to do that, even though SQLite doesn't like it.

Comment: I didn't see SQLite in the question, but that works just fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=849d2bf60826da517af5ae258f0e8d7b

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The extra parens don't work in SQLite (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aa45a274eda0487d4d289f706e59044b).  It is the only database where I have seen this.  I simply always put subqueries in their own parentheses (well, except when using SQLite).

Comment: I absolutely hate that ;) it just increases the noise when reading the query.